# Typescript errors with Union type in Redux component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have a particularly trying error cropping up in one of my Action Creator.

```
let approveEnquiry = (): AppThunkAction<StoreAction | AppThunkAction<any> | RouterAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Dispatch action then call the route
};

interface StoreAction {
    type: ActionType.SET_VALUE;
    fieldName: string;
    fieldValue: any;
}
```

And RouterAction comes from the `react-redux-router` type definitions and is of the form:

```
interface RouterAction {
    type: ... 
}
```

The problem seems to be the Union type cannot correctly differentiate between the `RouterAction` interface and the `StoreAction` interface.

The vexing thing is this appears to work on a colleagues machine and not on mine.

We are using Webpack and typescript v2.4.2

The error we are getting is warning that when attempting to dispatch an action which is part of the reducer it is expecting payload to be defined. This is because both `RouterAction` and Redux `Action` interfaces have a `type` property.

The solution was to include a cast for the item to the intended type to ensure that the correct part of the union type was used.

So in my action creator method:

```
dispatch(<StoreAction>{ 
    type: ActionType.SET_VALUE, 
    fieldName: '<FIELD_NAME>', 
    fieldValue: '<FIELD_VALUE>' 
});
```

This prevented the type system from thinking I was attempting to define a `RouterAction`. Without the type cast the warning suggested that I should have a `payload` property.

Just to note the reason we are adding the `AppThunkAction<any>`. The reason this is there is so I can dispatch actions which are part of other stores. So I can make a call like `dispatch(actionCreators.someAction());`. I am not attempting to call actions recursively, which I agree would not be desirable.

Wondered if anyone could share thoughts on how union types work when separate types in the union have one or more identical properties.

Thanks

Comment: Are you definitely using the same type definitions on both systems?

Comment: Please include the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: AFAIK We are using identical type definitions on both systems as defined by our package.json file.

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json ? is it the same as your colleague ?

Comment: `AppThunkAction<StoreAction | AppThunkAction<any> | RouterAction>` this is pretty strange, are you sure AppThunkAction is supposed to be used recursively ?

Comment: @adz5A tsconfigs are shared between machines. My suspiscion was perhaps we were using different versions of typescript. Verbose logging with webpack didn't confirm the version of typescript and I haven't found a way I trust to confirm this.

Comment: Hello, could you post the full error you're getting along with the dependencies you're using (  typescript, @types/* etc... ) ? Have you tried to reproduce with a simpler union type ?

Comment: @CaptainJohn I am currently seeing the exact same issue, trying to union with RouterAction. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @knighter I moved away from this particular project a while ago now. The solution/workaround is outlined in my question i.e. casting the event. HTH